# Will Ubuntu format my external hard drive?

Tags: dual-boot

I am using a [Toshiba Canvio Connect 2TB Portable Hard Drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CGUMS48) on my Microsoft Windows 7 laptop.

Also, I am testing [Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) by running it from my flash drive. I am planning to later dual boot Ubuntu alongside Microsoft Windows 7.

Will the files on my external hard drive be deleted when I use it on Ubuntu (since I have already been saving files on it from Windows)?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

Want to keep all your data?:

You should install Ubuntu on a separate partition. The most important thing is you should create a separate partition for Ubuntu manually, and you should select it while installing Ubuntu.

First create a separate partition for Ubuntu while running Windows (like a partition with more than 10 GB). Also create a small partition for the swap partition (size is equal to your RAM size).

- You should know the partition sizes you created so that you can identify them easily while installing Ubuntu.

See the below images - I picked them by googling so they won't be same as yours (like partition sizes and number of partitions).

The second important thing is while installing Ubuntu select "Something else".

[image]

It will allow you to select your manually created partition to install Ubuntu onto it.

Now select and edit the partition you created for Ubuntu. Be careful in selecting. Check twice that you selected the correct partition, not some other partition as you may lose data like before.

[image]

Select the format partition, use as mount point as shown in the image. The size is up to you.

After that, select the swap partition, and edit it as shown in the image (size is your choice).

[image]

After that select the "Device for boot loader installation" at the bottom and select the one with `/dev/sda` at the beginning.

[image]

Now you can select "install now" at the right bottom.

Comment: Just clarifying, the partitioning method you described will allow me to use my external hard drive on Ubuntu without deleting all the data on it, right? I'm not that good with English, so I am wondering if you are referring to keeping all the data on the external hard drive, or the internal hard drive on my laptop? Thanks so much for replying :)

Comment: You can keep all the data in your external drive (or your internal, if you want) while using Ubuntu, just partition it following the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

While it shouldn't format the drive unless you manually tell it to do so, if you are paranoid you can physically remove the external drive [after unmounting] when you are using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want Ubuntu to install on the external drive, you can choose to install it next to Windows.  (The first option on the drive installation choice.)

It should never touch the external drive if you do that.

You can also install it on the external drive.  You may have to choose to resize the partition.  On a 1.5 TB external drive, with only a few hundred MB used, the process started and after a short said it would be finished in about 20 hours.

I was successful and was able to boot Ubuntu from grub on the internal drive to the OS on the external drive.  Ubuntu was able to read both drives quite well.  I eventually installed it on the internal drive. It's faster that way.

BTW, Ubuntu can read either partition, but Microsoft cannot read the Ubuntu partitions.